# Applying Textures in Blender

Tags: texturing

Hello I'm pretty new to Blender, and I need some help with applying premade textures to models I've downloaded from blendswap.

So If I download this model for example: http://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/78361
and import it to blender, the model added doesn't have the texture. All the models that I import look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fktfj.png

How do i go about adding the texture that the author already made?

Comment: Your viewport is using solid shading, which looks right. Does rendered preview or full render show the material? You change the viewport to rendered preview in the menu next to `Object Mode`

Comment: Have you tried Shift-Z? that will take you into rendered mode. Also, how did you "import" the model, if you used link or append, you may have left the material behind!

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by import? It is already a blend file, so you can only append or link data from the file into another file.

If you are appending some parts, make sure you are selecting everything you need and, in that case, that you change your render engine to cycles before rendering (it will render grey otherwise).
It should render correctly, that model doesn't have much for textures, the most noticeable is the chair color.

In the viewport, everything will look grey if you are on 'solid mode'. See more on that here: http://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/shading.html

Answer (score 0):

You are using the Cycles Render, so the colour does not show up in the viewport, but if you hit `Shift`+`Z` to change to Rendered View, you can see the image rendered in the view port and then you can see the colours.